# Manual code flow in Azure AD

Tags: azure, active-directory, oauth-2.0

In our quest to create a custom login page in combination with Azure Active Directory we would like to use the Code Flow (as MS does in their own sign-in page) when sending user and password to AD.

Currently, in our login page we are logging the user in using AquireToken with the UserCredential class, but that only gives us access and refreshtoken.

```
UserCredential uc = new UserCredential(userName, password);

result = authContext.AcquireToken(resource, clientId, uc);
```

Microsoft has mentioned that its a bad idea (security) to use UserCredential to login a user but fail to mention any exact reasons. This request is made from the web Server to AD Server, so I don't see any security issues here. They do want us to buy the Premium edition of Azure AD, but its too expensive calculated with millions of users.

Any suggestions are most welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Letting apps collect users credentials in their own UI is bad security practice and breaks usability. Here are some of the reasons why:

1. it teaches users to enter their credentials into any prompt without discernment
2. it won't work with password managers
3. it prevents users from enjoying single sign in with other apps, or from selecting an account from a list
4. it forces users to reenter credentials where they could have been signed in silently by the OS or an authentication broker app. For example, on a domain joined PC.
5. Auth to your app will fail for users who have turned on two-factor authentication.
6. If you're building a multi tenanted app, you will loose the ability to leverage Azure AD's home realm discovery flow.

Hope this helps,
Ariel.

Comment: Hi Arial, thanks for replying. 1. This is a project funded by the trade/industry association itself so trust is already there. 2. Its just a login website like login.windows.net so password managers should work. 3. Yes, but still only Azure AD apps or accounts? 4. I believe OS sign-in can be archived on a website!? 5. True, that functionality would need be developed inhouse. 6. True.

Comment: The biggest reason we want to create our own sign-in webpage is to allow users to use any email for sign-in. It is not working for us that a Microsoft or AD domain email is required. Any changes in the pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

If your app is going to support other identities than Azure AD or Microsoft accounts (formerly Live ID), then in the short term you should show other sign in buttons in your app. Longer term: we are working on adding support for social IdPs on Azure AD (these are the ACS features that we're bringing over to Azure AD).

Re: using any email address as a sign-in string: can you clarify what you mean? Are you trying to support credentials local to your app (as opposed to relying on Azure AD)? If you share some mocks of the experience you have in mind, I'll be happy to provide feedback. You can reach me at myfirstname.mylastname at Microsoft.com.

Comment: Thanks again Ariel, I will email you.